# Custom Spinner set Text

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

Hello I am using a custom adaptar for a spinner, but when I select an item from the spinner no text is set on the spinner with my selected choice. What am I doing wrong? the following code is my adapter:

```
 private  class ListadapterUnicaCidades extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _list1;
            public ListadapterUnicaCidades(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pperguntalist) {
                // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                _list1 = cidadeslist;
            }

            /**
             * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of
             * speeches in our array.
             * 
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
             */
            public int getCount() {

                // return BabbleMainListParse.getNumOfBabbles();
                return _list1.size();
            }

            /**
             * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
             * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
             * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
             * list.
             * 
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
             */
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return _list1.get(position);
            }

            /**
             * Use the array index as a unique id.
             * 
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
             */
            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            /**
             * Make a view to hold each row.
             * 
             * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
             *      android.view.ViewGroup)
             */
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {

                Log.d("disponiveislist", "getView");
                // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid
                // unneccessary calls
                // to findViewById() on each row.
                ViewHolder holder;

                // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is
                // no need
                // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
                // supplied
                // by ListView is null.
                if (convertView == null) 
                {


                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, parent,false);
                    Log.d("ConvertView",convertView.toString());

                    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
                    // views
                    // we want to bind data to.
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.listtexto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
                //holder.txtVilleListTitle.setText(VilleMainListParse.getMsgTitle(position));


             Log.d("_List", _list1.toString());
             holder.listtexto.setText(_list1.get(position).get("DESIGNACAO"));

                return convertView;
            }

             class ViewHolder
            {
                TextView listtexto;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

point 1

your are not using pperguntalist

```
public ListadapterUnicaCidades(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pperguntalist) {
```

point 2: iff you want to set what you are seeing in sppiner list use

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
                return _list1.get(position).get("DESIGNACAO");//_list1.get(position);
            }
```

Comment: it is still the same. Is it possible to change the android.layout?